# Do the residents of Facade talk in a language that can be understood?

Tags: nier-replicant-1.22474487139

When you first get to Facade, in game the protagonist can't understand the villagers.

But the VO really sounds like Japanese. Thing is, I do not know any japanese, so I can't tell if it is or its just gibberish that sounds like japanese (they probably kept the VO that was created in japanese for them)

So is the VO of the residents of facade a language (that if you know that language you may know what they are saying) or is it just gibberish that happens to sound like japanese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://nier.fandom.com/wiki/Facade), the language of Facade residents is an original language, and was derived from the Japanese hiragana (writing system).

> A 4Gamer interview revealed that the residents of Facade speak an original language that is meant to be gibberish from scrambled Japanese hiragana. However, the programmer who created the original language program couldn't fix the bugs where it created actual Japanese words. Yoko casually decided that they fit the mood anyway and left them in, causing an accidental misconception that contemporary Japanese still existed in NieR's continuity

The interview (in Japanese) can be found [here](https://www.4gamer.net/games/098/G009875/20100709053/index_2.html)

Comment: Ah so that explains. It is derived from japanese so thats why it sounds like it (and then they probably didn't redo that work for the english version because it would be silly since its supposed to be a ununderstandable language anyways.).